# Connecting delta sharing to other services

Tags: apache-spark, powerbi, databricks, delta-lake, delta-sharing

I have a delta sharing server running, but can't access it in Power BI - "Access to the resource is forbidden", Spark doesn't work either - "FileReadException: Error while reading file delta-sharing". I can see in logs that my delta sharing server have those incoming requests and sends a response, but I never get response on the other end(power bi and spark).
In the same time I can make a request and everything works as expected if use cURL or Postman. Any ideas what it might be?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this the open-source Delta Sharing server or via a Databricks instance of Delta Sharing?

Comment: @DennyLee open source on Azure VM, I followed that guide
https://medium.com/@willgirten/deploy-a-delta-sharing-server-on-azure-26915d74961

Comment: To confirm, when you're running this in Spark, are you running an instance on the VM you created to access to those files?  It seems like your VM does not have access to the file system.

Comment: Have you tried setting the row limit higher than the default of 1M in PowerBI? That was causing the error for me recently.